# What hints at the identity of the fourth man?

Tags: comics, dc, planetary

In Chapter Twelve of Planetary, it is revealed that

> Elijah Snow is the fourth man, whose memory was wiped by The Four.

I suspect there are more than a few hints at this fact, and noticed a couple myself. What foreshadows this reveal, both visually and in the dialogue/story?